# click on body except on specific div

Tags: jquery

I want to do something clicking on `body`, except on `menutop` which is inside the `body`.

```
<body>
<div id="menutop">lorem ipsum...</div>
...
</body>
```

js

```
$("body").not($("#menutop")).click(function(){
    console.log("323");
});
```

also tried

```
var n = $("#menutop");
$("body:not(n)").click(function(){
    console.log("323");
});
```

but clicking on `menutop` in both cases console shows `323`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The selector `$("body").not($("#menutop"))` will select the `body` element if it is not the `#menutop` element. Since the `body` element clearly isn't `#menutop` element, the `body` element is still selected and the click event is attached to it.

Even if you click on the `#menutop` element, the click event will still bubble up and trigger the click event on the `body` element, therefore one option is to make a check to see if `event.target` is the `#menutop` element:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#menutop').length) {
    // ... clicked on the 'body', but not inside of #menutop
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could also suppress the event bubbling and [stop event propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) when clicking in the `#menutop` element:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  // ... clicked on the 'body', but not inside of #menutop
});
$('#menutop').on('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` on the menutop element to prevent click through to the body below.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxozmP) for the solution

**JS**

```
$("body").click(function(){
    alert("323");
});

$("#menutop").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menutop').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

stopPropagation() will keep your click from propagating down and activating a click on the body.

Answer (score 2):

We will handle click event of whole body, and then identify the source element of event as below

- If click event triggered from the target element (#menutop)
  document.getElementById("menutop").isSameNode(event.target)
- If click event triggered from any of descendants of target element (#menutop)
  document.getElementById("menutop").contains(event.target)

We will ignore event triggered for above two cases and perform required operations for rest triggered events.

```
$("body").click(function(event){
    if(
        document.getElementById("menutop").isSameNode(event.target) 
        || document.getElementById("menutop").contains(event.target)
    ){
        // Event triggered from within the #menutop div element
        // Do nothing and return
        return;
    }
    // We are here because click event triggered from outside of #menutop div element
    alert('Click event triggered from outside of #menutop div element');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a non-jquery example, as I don't have jquery available on my project. This works great!