# Click listener on body except certain div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a table header where I am showing Icon based on radio value click on row.

So, default it is **AddIcon** where `onClick` I would add one more row to the table and if I click any row then I am showing **EditIcon** and **DeleteIcon** simultaneously.

But how do I switch back to **AddIcon** since I am having radioValue already selected therefore I want listen click listener except this div so that I can set state of radio value again.

Comment: add functionality so that when you click on the already selected row it clears the selection.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli exactly I thought the same thing but then it would not be called a radio button. Have you seen a radio button where you click on it then it would deselect the selection made?

Answer (score 0):

add handler function that toggle between `true` and `false` whenever you click ?

Comment: yes but how do make a listener which will listen all click events except to this table? This is my problem. Then I will add handler to set radioValue

Comment: what do you mean all click events ?

Comment: all click events sounded little weird what I meant here is if I click anywhere else except on the div in which I am having table I want to set some value by calling a function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661797/jquery-click-anywhere-in-the-page-except-on-1-div

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328016/click-on-body-except-on-specific-div/35328119 this one is more appropriate something like this  `$("body").not($("#menutop"))`

Comment: I want the same thing in reactjs not jquery

Comment: i don't thing that this way is best practice , i really don't recommend it

Comment: https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/#tables Look here the tables where checkboxes are mentioned I replaced these checkboxes with radio button therefore how deselect the radio button. The question is pretty simple.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you have done , pls add some code... For me it's sound just as toggle function